# Glossaries - How to retrieve referencing when using nonumberlist?

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries, glossaries-extra, ref

At the beginning, I use the [glossaries package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) with the following options :

```
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{long3col-booktabs}
```

Since I add some options (and change the style) to glossaries, I lose the useful references in resulting pdf :

```
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{long-booktabs}
```

Before :

[image]

After :

[image]

Can you help me to retrieve this behaviour with actual configuration ?
I didn't find something useful about that in the docs ...

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the information about that in the [HTML](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html) docs (and not in the PDF version)

[image]